# set copy array of float to multidimensional array

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, arduino

I am trying to understand pointers in c/arduino, and its giving me problems :)

I have a function that creates and returns a pointer to an array of floats:

```
float* CreateArray(int i) {
    float test[2];
    test[0] = float(i+1); 
    test[1] = float(i+2);
    return test;
}
```

I have also defined a multidimensional array:

```
float data[2][2];
```

Before I do anything I expect data to look like this: (which it does)

```
0 0
0 0
```

When I run the following code:

```
float* array = CreateArray(22);
*data[1] = *array;
```

I expect data to look like this:

```
0  0
23 24
```

But it looks like this:

```
0  0
23 0
```

Somehow the information that the created array was a float[2] is lost, and when I try to cast it to float[2] I get:

```
ISO C++ forbids casting to an array type 'float [2]'
```

Comment: You are returning an address to local variable which is deleted when you go out of scope

Comment: *data[1] is the same as data[1][0]. *array is the same as array[0]. If you want to copy whole arrays you need to loop or use memcpy().

Comment: ah yes of course that makes sense its out of scope

Comment: @happy I well receive you accept my answer to solve your problems. If you have any additional questions or problems, don't hesitate to  ask, and point me to another question perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a pointer returned from a locally defined raw array on the stack, you must use a [**`std::array`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) to make the returned values accessible:

```
std::array<float,2> CreateArray(int i) {
    std::array<float,2> test;
    test[0] = float(i+1); 
    test[1] = float(i+2);
    return test;
}
```

This should fix all of your problems regarding undefined behavior, as stated in the [formerly marked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope) to this question.